# How to solve equation

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms

I have a problem to solve that equation

$\log_{4}\left(x\right) = -2x + 9$

i know that answer is 4
but what is step by step solution.

Comment: See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a systematic approach, but you can proceed as follows:
Let $x > 0$ be such that $\log_4 x = -2x +9$. Then $x= 4^{-2x}4^9 = \frac{2^{18}}{e^{2\ln4\cdot x}}$, so that ${x}{e^{2\ln4 x}} = 2^{18}$, and
$$
{2\ln4\cdot x}{e^{2\ln4\cdot x}} = 2^{19}\ln 4 \tag{1}
$$
It is not too hard to show that the function $f\colon y > 0 \mapsto {y}{e^y}$ is increasing on $(0,\infty)$; since $f(0)=0$ and $2^{19}\ln 4 > 0$, this implies that the only possible solution is for some $y\stackrel{\rm{}def}{=}2\ln4\cdot x$ being in $(0,\infty)$. In particular, there is at most *one* solution, so *if you happen to find one, you'd be done.*

Now, by magic, once you have found that the "easy" solution $x=4$ works (in (1) and in the original equation), you proved that it was the only one.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should notice that this is an equation to be solved for $x>0$. 
Now compute the derivative of $f(x)=\log_4x+2x-9$. You have $f'(x)=1/(x\ln4)+2$. For $x>0$ this is positive so $f$ is strictly increasing on $(0,\infty)$.
As you know one solution that is reasonably easy to guess, you should be able to conclude yourself.

In case you don't know any solution to this type of equation, the reasoning I have written is only able to say if there exists a solution or not. As @TooOldFor Math pointed out, the general solution of this kind of equation ($\ln x=ax+b$) is given by the Lambert W function, which is a special (*i.e.* complicated) function.